# Sendgrid api substitutions not working for multiple emails

Tags: asp.net, sendgrid

how to send email to multiple recipents with substitutions in sendgrid email in c# ?
Sendgrid api substitutions are not working for multiple receipents.
I am using Sendgrid to send emails with templates that contain multiple variables. Everything works well when I have only one recipient for an email.

When I have multiple recipients either in To or one in To and one in Cc, the first email is ok but the following have empty strings in the substition tags.

Below is my code :

```
var message = new SendGridMessage();
message.Subject = fullName + " has shared SmartForm with you for  " + PLConstants.APP_NAME;
message.EnableTemplateEngine(PLConstants.SEND_SMARTFORM_EMAIL_TOUSER);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailIds))
{
    string[] bccAddressField = emailIds.Split(',');                    

    for (int icount = 0; icount < bccAddressField.Length; icount++)
    {
        if (bccAddressField[icount].ToString() != "")
        {
            if (message.To.Length == 0)
            {
                message.AddTo(bccAddressField[icount].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                //message.AddTo(bccAddressField[icount].ToString());
                message.AddBcc(new EmailAddress(bccAddressField[icount].ToString()).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

string profileUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", PLConstants.SMARTLINK_URL,(HttpContext.Current.Session[PLConstants.SESSION_USERNAME].ToString()));
message.AddSubstitution("{SenderName}",new List<string> { (HttpContext.Current.Session[PLConstants.SESSION_FIRST_NAME].ToString()) });
message.AddSubstitution("{SmartListingName}", new List<string> { objSmartListingModel.Title });
message.AddSubstitution("{SmartListingLink}", new List<string> { smartListingLink });
message.AddSubstitution("{SmartListingRedirectionLink}", new List<string> { smartListingRedirectionLink });

message.Html = " ";
Mailer.SendEmail(message);
```

Comment: are you using V3 api to send the email ? what is `Mailer.SendEmail(message);` this is not the correct way to send the mail

Comment: Actually "Mailer" is my class in which i have maintained all mail sending functions and "SendEmail" is one of them.

Comment: can you post the Mailer class?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Now i found the solution as per my last answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for giving response.Actually i found answer from @grishma.
For multiple receipients, i have passed pass substituions values with respective number of receipients.

eg. if i have 4 receipients then i have to add substitutions like : 
message.AddSubstitution("{SmartListingLink}", new List { "Link1","Link2","Link3" });

Answer (score 0):

if your list of recipients are in "To" string as follows, please try to add recipients as follows. You can use this for CC / Bcc as well.

```
        string To = "a@a.com; b@b.com";

        //create the mail message
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        //set the addresses
        string[] arrTo = To.Split(';');
        for (int i = 0; i < arrTo.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arrTo[i].Trim()))
            mail.To.Add(arrTo[i].Trim());
        }

            SmtpClient smtp = null;
            smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", Convert.ToInt32(587));
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");  
            smtp.Credentials = credentials;
            smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I have not used Mail Message i have used sendgridmessage object

Comment: did you check this : https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/personalizations.html

Comment: yes i have checked this but personalization is not there in my library functions